# Is there a way to return a document body after indexing?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am looking to return the full contents of a document after it is indexed. Elastic only returns:

```
{ 
    _index: 'doc-dataset',
    _type: 'my-doc',
    _id: 'AVt8nyuxRNHpCQ5APUtx',
    _version: 1,
    result: 'created',
    _shards: { total: 2, successful: 1, failed: 0 },
    created: true,
    status: 201 
}
```

I would like it to return something like:

```
{ 
    _index: 'doc-dataset',
    _type: 'my-doc',
    _id: 'AVt8nyuxRNHpCQ5APUtx',
    _version: 1,
    result: 'created',
    _shards: { total: 2, successful: 1, failed: 0 },
    created: true,
    status: 201,
    source:{
        prop: value,
        prop: value,
        ...
        prop: value
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: No, you need to make a `GET doc-dataset/my-doc/AVt8nyuxRNHpCQ5APUtx ` call immediately after indexing it and you'll get the document. But why would you get a document that you've just indexed (i.e. you have the source body already)

Answer (score -1):

GET /index_name/_search

will give you all the documents along with properties and its respective values.

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question. Have a look at @Val comment below the question for further understanding.